# Midnight Commander starts bash shell with wrong option? 'bash -rcfile .bashrc'. Single -

Tags: bash, mc

I noticed that when mc is started, a process appears with command line like this

```
bash -rcfile .bashrc
```

Note single dash. Bash does have the rcfile option but that supposed to be specified with double dash, not single.
Is there any hidden sense behind this command or just a bug/typo in the Midnight Commander ?

Comment: Looks like a bug: https://github.com/MidnightCommander/mc/blob/35b3192f41bb94f3397d9e77913023eb9dc1dfbd/src/subshell/common.c#L378

Comment: Probably yes. Since .bashrc is default rcfile for bash, it still is taken by bash at its start. Kind of 'does not hurt' bug.
UNLESS rcfile is not redefined for mc:
https://github.com/MidnightCommander/mc/blob/35b3192f41bb94f3397d9e77913023eb9dc1dfbd/src/subshell/common.c#L295